# Angular Dialog passed by function

Tags: angular, dialog

I have one problem. I have some components, one them receive a input with array object, this object is `{ name: 'buttonname', click: () => {}}`. I need to pass one function in click property, that function it will open the dialog component.

I have no idea how to do it. I tried create another class injecting MatDialog, but I can instantiate this class because the MatDialog has parameters.

Project Example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-htrzbk

Please, help me

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by using inheritance, for example you'll have the following code:

```
abstract class ConfigType {
    name: string
    data: string;
    abstract clickAction(): void;
}
```

then you inherit this class with a certain clickAction logic like this:

```
class DialogOpen extends ConfigType {
    data = "some param";
    clickAction() {
      console.log("Dialog opened " + this.data);
    }
 }
```

or a class for the log like this:

```
class ConsoleLog extends ConfigType {
    clickAction() {
      console.log("Barcode created");
    }
 }
```

You can then use this function within your main component like below

HTML:

```
<button (click)="btn.clickAction()" *ngFor="let btn of config">{{btn.name}}</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the problem is the MatDialog is generally injected dependence in component constructor. How I will use the component MatDialog in a simple class?

Comment: You could pass it onto the class by using the constructor, you might even be able to inject it straight into the class. Not sure about that though